# Google Script inserting an image without URL to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is to request an image from an endpoint that returns its contents (i.e a blob) and insert  it to a cell. Note that the image has not been persisted anywhere, so it does not have a URL. In case I were a JavaScript web developer, I could use an Image object and set its src to the result of URL.createObjectURL(...). But I need to solve this in a Google Script, based on JS.

In the Google Script docs there is this example:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var blob = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');
sheet.insertImage(blob, 1, 1);
```

I would expect that this code gets the image from the endpoint and inserts it in cell A1:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'MY_SPREADSHEET_URL';
  var SHEET_NAME = 'SHEET_NAME';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "ENDPOINT_URL").getContent();

  var image = Utilities.newBlob(response, "image/jpeg", "img.jpeg");
  sheet.insertImage(image, 1, 1);
}
```

However, I get an error saying that the type of my image variable (that is Blob) it is not supported.

> The blob format is unsupported. at onOpen.

The [official docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(Byte,String,String)) say that the method newBlob returns a Blob object.
What am I missing?

Comment: I thought that the error message of `The blob format is unsupported.`, the retrieved data from the URL of `ENDPOINT_URL` might not be the image data. So, in your situation, can I ask you about whether `ENDPOINT_URL` is the direct link of the image?

Comment: Also I am not sure, if there is indeed an image in the webpage without a URL. I would like to be proven wrong and learn something new but I haven't seen an image without a url.. But your question depends 100% on what this `"ENDPOINT_URL"` so I don't think you can get an answer without reaviling some more info about it.

Comment: I have formulated my text a bit confusingly, sorry for that. I meant that ENDPOINT_URL is the URL to which the GET request is made, the server generates the image and returns it as an InputStreamResource. By image URL I meant the URL at which an image is stored (for instance, on AWS S3). Alas, just calling the insertImage method with ENDPOINT_URL solves my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`HTTPResponse.getAs(contentType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getascontenttype) like:

> `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("ENDPOINT_URL").getAs('image/jpeg')`

which returns a Blob. Then insert into sheets using [Sheet.insertImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row) like:

> `sheet.insertImage(response, 1, 1);`

And skip the creation of the Blob. But as the comments tell you, the validity of the object will depend on what lives at `'ENDPOINT_URL'`

Comment: Even simply sheet.insertImage("ENDPOINT_URL", 1, 1) does the trick. Your answer also works, and it is that led me towards the solution, so I'm accepting it. Thank you!